# XML Webservice not wrorking VB ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, web-services

I have a web method defined in my asmx file like this

```
  <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Function HelloWorld(ByVal theResp As String) As String
        Return "HelloWorl"+ theResp
    End Function
```

and it works perfectly fine when I use ajax to send it a test and get it back

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: "/GettingData.asmx/HelloWorld",        
    dataType:"text",       
    data: "It's me",
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {           
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("there is a problemsending the XML");
    }
});
```

I am getting a 500 internal server error and upon closer inspection I see that the response text says that

```
responseText: "System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: paramType.↵ at    
System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection  
collection)↵   
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()↵
```

I found a small thread that might shed some light, but it is not helping me. http://forums.asp.net/t/1752866.aspx/1 this is becuase I am not sure how my code from the client side (in javascript) will call theResp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
data: { theResp: "It's me" },
```

Comment: Will he need to change his dataType to json?

Comment: I believe dataType is the return type. The `$.ajax` docs say the data property can be a plain object.

Comment: I though that if you send an object type it get converted into a query string, because of the processData default is true. So I though that passing in a string would be fine but I guess I have to wrap it in an object so it can be converted to a string?

Comment: I assume that if you just send a string, it doesn't know what parameter to match that up with on the server side.

Comment: oh ok, so if I send the object I have to make sure the object has the same name.

Comment: @JackThor See my last comment. I guess if you only have one parameter, it could assume that the value you send is intended for that one parameter, but if you have two parameters, you would certainly have to specify which value was for which parameter.